# How To change default color of Mode.Clear?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I want to change the default color of the Mode.Clear.
In my App I am using a erase method in which the Clear option leaves a black line first , and then i clearing the image . I want to use different color in place of it depending upon my background. Here is my code...

**Erase Method:**

```
public void erase(View v)

{
    //mPaint=new Paint();
   //mPaint.setAlpha(0);


//mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
   //mPaint.setARGB(0, 255, 255, 255);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
    //mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
       //mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
      // mPaint.setStrokeWidth(45);
    // mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterD

//uff.Mode.CLEAR));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct solution for that.  I have a workaround for it:

1. During "move" event, show path as normal with the paint's Xfermode set to null.
2. During "touch up" event, before drawing on canvas, set the paint's Xfermode to clear.
3. Set the paint's Xfermode to null after drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have used a kind of trick to remove the black line.In my erase button, I have set the color to white, instead of using XferMode..

```
if(erase){
paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}
```